# Using a factor as both fixed and random in linear mixed models

Tags: r, random, fixed, lme4

I would like to know if it is acceptable to use a factor as both fixed and random. My understanding is that it is not a general practice.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3881361/

http://avesbiodiv.mncn.csic.es/estadistica/curso2011/regm26.pdf

In the following model, I am using `Sp` as a fixed as well as random factor, and my model does not converge.

```
Model1 <- lmer (C1 ~ Place*Voicing*Length*Sp + 
     (1+Place+Voicing+Length|Sp),data = 
C1,control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=50000)))
anova (Model1)

str(LME_Model1)

$ Sp      : Factor w/ 5 levels
$ Place   : Factor w/ 3 levels
$ Voicing : Factor w/ 2 levels
$ Length  : Factor w/ 2 levels

Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
```

If I exclude `Sp` from the fixed factors, then the model converges. 
Could someone explain whether it is OK to use `Sp` as a fixed factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you want to fit is theoretically OK but practically difficult.

To be more precise, when you say "include a factor as both fixed and random" you mean "include a factor as both fixed and *as a term within a particular grouping variable". I would typically interpret "include `g` as a a random effect" as "include `g` as a random effect *grouping variable*", i.e. something like `(1|g)`.

When you include `(1+Place+Voicing+Length|Sp)` in your model, what you are assuming is that the effect of `Place`, `Voicing`, and `Length` are allowed to vary across levels of the grouping variable (`Sp`). Given that you are using a [randomized block design](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri332.htm) (each, or at least most, levels of `Sp` have observations for all, or most, of the levels of `Place`, `Voicing`, and `Length`), this variability is *theoretically* estimable.

However ... you will typically need a big experiment if you want to estimate all of this variability. Suppose `Place`, `Voicing`, and `Length` have `m1`, `m2`, and `m3` levels respectively. `lme4` assumes that all of the terms included for a particular grouping variable could covary; this means that you'll be estimating a variance-covariance matrix with `1+m1+m2+m3-3 = m1+m2+m3-2` rows and columns (the different effects share an intercept term), or a total of `(m1+m2+m3-2)*(m1+m2+m3-1)/2` variance-covariance parameters - a minimum of 10, if those are each two-level factors.

There is a great deal of debate about the proper procedure when a mixed model is theoretically identifiable, but you don't practically have enough data to fit the maximal model. Some discussion is given [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1). You could fit the maximal model and throw away terms in some sensible order until it's no longer overspecified; use a Bayesian method, specifying priors to regularize the model; try to decide *a priori* on a simpler model ...

Comment: Thanks Ben! I agree that I need a large set of data to use the current model. I have around 300 data points.  In my field (Phonetics), journal reviewers ask to do LME models even if the data are not large enough. So it's a new trend. "To be more precise, when you say "include a factor as both fixed and random" you mean "include a factor as both fixed and *as a term within a particular grouping variable". I would typically interpret "include g as a a random effect" as "include g as a random effect grouping variable", i.e. something like (1|g). That's exactly right! And thanks for the web links.